# How to simplify; dozens of Excel Tabs with the same underlying VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba

I have 51 unique tabs in a workbook.  Each tab has a bit of code that will update the 52nd tab when certain cells are changed on the 51.   Bottom line, it's an audit history of the 2 cells on each of the 51 tabs.

I've pieced together the following code that I drop onto each worsheets VBA section.  The problem is that I have to do this for every single sheet in the workbook.  I'd think that I should be able to have just a single common call to the meat of the VBA...

```
Dim PreVal

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$D$1" Or Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
    PreVal = Target.Value
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$D$1" Then
    If Target.Value <> PreVal Then
        SomethingSomewhere = Value
        PreVal = Target.Value
    End If
End If

If Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
    If Target.Value <> PreVal Then
        SomethingSomewhere = Value
        PreVal = Target.Value
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

It works wonderfully, just managing any changes needs to be done on every single sheet..

BTW, the SomethingSomewhere equals Value  sets the app user name, sheet name, preval, target value, and date time into columns on the logging page

Comment: Consider using the [`Workbook.SheetChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) and [`Workbook.SheetSelectionChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetselectionchange) events instead.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subroutine that contains the logic and then create the application you drop on to each sheet.  This application will call the subroutine.  Now, when you change the subroutine, all of the sheets will pickup the same modification.

Comment: In simplifying my question (got rid of some junk) it made it a little more understandable for me...  So just create a module and pass the action from the worksheet events to the module procedures to do the work.  I have to remember how to do some of that ;-)  I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Worksheet events, use their corresponding Workbook events: [`Workbook.SheetSelectionChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetselectionchange) and [`Workbook.SheetChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange). These fire whenever *any* worksheet has a selection change or cell change.

Add these to the `ThisWorkbook` code module.

```
Dim PreVal

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$D$1" Or Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
        PreVal = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Address = "$D$1" Or Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
        If Target.Value <> PreVal Then
            SomethingSomewhere = Value
            PreVal = Target.Value
        End If
    End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You can modify these to ignore the logging page by checking `Sh.Name`, for example.